# Xdebug не работает с браузером

Tags: php, phpstorm

Не работает Xdebug в связке PHPStorm и Ubuntu 22 + Сhrome, отображает только данные в PHPStorm, но никак не связывается с браузером, не отображает ни $_SESSION, ни $_COOKIE, + при обновлении страницы не обновляет данные в отладке.

Вот что отображает у меня: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот что у автора:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мои настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И плюсом прописал такие настройки в php.ini:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Comment: *"А вот что у автора"* --- у какого такого автора? И почему тогда его и не спросить почему так?

Comment: Правильно было бы описать в вопросе все свои шаги и все настройки, что где как было написано, а не кидать два скрина, которые не говорят никому ни о чём

Comment: У автора возможности нет спросить, а по настройкам да, сейчас дополню

Comment: Я перелопатил весь интернет, пробовал разные настройки, но мне все равно пишет "waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'XXXXX'", как исправить эту ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Заработало, ура!!! Помогло следующее, настраивал по этому видео https://youtu.be/auDs9OqEgMA?si=e4sQhWYQ_H2NVhXr, а во всех php.ini, включая xdebug.ini вписал это!:

> zend_extension=xdebug.so xdebug.mode = debug xdebug.client_host =
> 127.0.0.1 ;# For PhpStorm set below to 9000 (or update IDE's settings). xdebug.client_port = 9003 xdebug.start_with_request=yes
> xdebug.log="/var/log/nginx/xdebug.log" xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
> xdebug.discover_client_host=false